# Safari breaks when using exclamation mark in Angular condition

Tags: angularjs, mobile-safari

This sounds wacky but we're currently consistently able to reproduce this issue, and I wanted to know if anyone has seen anything like it, or knows what could be causing it.

We have an Angular 1.4.1 application, and in some of our html partials we have conditions in the following form:

```
<div ng-if="!obj.myvar">
    ... contents ...
</div>
```

Where in your JS you've set up your scope accordingly:

```
$scope.obj = { myvar: false }
```

This works as expected in all browsers, **except** iOS Safari (we've seen this on iPhone and iPad):

- On the initial load, all elements following the ng-if fail to load
- If you manually refresh the page, it will then work as expected

We've found that changing the syntax to this fixes the issue:

```
<div ng-if="obj.myvar === false">
    ... contents ...
</div>
```

But I'm not hugely satisfied with that as a solution, and it doesn't explain why this issue is happening at all.

*Word of warning if you're trying to replicate this - this isn't reproducible on jsFiddle. I assume that's because the results window isn't a "true" browser.*

Comment: I've tested it on iOS 8.1 on iPhone 6 but wasn't able to reproduce this error. Can you post relevant code in a fiddle? Some have the option to open the result in a new page.

Comment: Working on getting a reproducible example outside of our codebase. Our latest thinking is that it could be due to the strange scope inheritance that ngIf statements cause - potentially our variables are being set after the ngIf condition is executed... but that wouldn't explain why we're only seeing this on iOS Safari.